# Update Where equivalent

Tags: r, dataframe

I am currently trying to update the column "e" for any rows where

```
for(col in colnames(df))
{
  df$e[is.na(df[col])] <- paste(col, "empty - excluded:", " ")
}
```

This works. However, how would I go about appending the new text to the current value in the cell?

I'm used to SQL:

```
UPDATE df SET e = e & " excluded" WHERE NZ(col, '') = ''
```

Comment: Can you illustrate your desired output? Providing a reproducible example would probably clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this (untested)

```
df[,"e"] <- ""
for (col in colnames(df)) {
    idx <- which(is.na(df[,col])
    df[idx, "e"] <- paste(df[idx, "e"], col, sep=", ")
}
df[,"e"] <- ifelse(df[,"e"]!="", paste(df[,"e"], "empty - excluded")
```

This would first collect the NA columns and later add the string "empty - excluded".